# Ordering can't take parameter type for context bound

Tags: scala

The following code is using context bound:

```
def max[T: Ordering](a: T, b: T): T = {
  val ord = implicitly(Ordering[T])
  if (ord.compare(a, b) > 0) a else b
}
```

In the `[T:Ordering]` part, Ordering doesn't take type parameter, if I write as
`[T:Ordering[T]]`,  the compiler complains that Ordering can't take type parameter.

But Ordering indeed could take type parameter, and I think generic type must take type parameter.

Do I miss some special rules here?

Thanks

Comment: Note that your `implicitly(Ordering[T])` works solely because there is an `Ordering.apply[T]` method; when you call `implicitly`, you pass it the desired type: `implicitly[Ordering[T]]`, however, in this case `implicitly[Ordering[T]]` is the same as `Ordering.apply[T]` or indeed `Ordering[T]`, so you can omit `implicitly` at all.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirMatveev for the great answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[Left: Right]` (a *context bound*) requires types `Left` of some kind `k` and `Right` of kind `k -> *`. That is, `Left` is some type or a type constructor, and `Right` is type constructor that can take `Left` as an argument to produce a concrete type. So, `Right` is never a concrete type, but `Right[Left]` always is.

Since all that is probably mathy gibberish: `[T: Ordering]` desugars to `implicit ord: Ordering[T]`, which works, but `[T: Ordering[T]]` desugars to `implicit fail: Ordering[T][T]`, which is nonsense. So, to your claim that `Ordering` needs a type argument, I say that it *does* need one, but instead of *you* writing the type argument, the *compiler* does it for you. That's why context bounds were created, so that when you write `[T: Ordering]` you don't need to write `T` twice.

Comment: Thanks @HTNW for the great answer.